# linphonecsh - when to call exit?

Tags: linphone

According to [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/linphonecsh.1.html), linphonesh is meant to execute VOIP calls from scripts. I got it to work, but how do I tell when a call has hung up so that I can then call the `exit` option.

The following work fine:

```
linphonecsh -c myconfigfile
linphonecsh dial 721234
```

How do I know when to invoke:

```
linphonecsh exit
```

Answer (score 0):

When the call is done (either party hangs up or call is not picked up after the timeout period), asterisk adds a new line to the CDR file, Master.csv.

So, after dialing, I scan the last line of `/var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv/Master.csv` every few seconds to detect a change.

This works well when there are no errors.